# PHP Getting the value after submit of array variables

Tags: php, html, dynamic, wamp

In my php code, i have few dynamic textboxes. i have given name through echo,

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {    
echo "<td><input type='text' name='avar[$i]'/></td>";
}
```

this dynamic textbox is under form tag. After submit i want to receive the values entered in the dynamically generated textboxes. I tried this way,

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {    
echo $_POST['avar'].[$i];
}
```

but it results in an error "Notice: Undefined offset: 1". Please suggest

Comment: try  print_r($_POST['avar']) ;  or  print_r($_POST). can you post result of this ?

Comment: @user2431351: see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18280720/1438393) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access an undefined index.

Try this instead:

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {    
echo $_POST['avar'][$i];
}
```

Working version:

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { //check if form submitted
    for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {    
    echo $_POST['avar'][$i];
    }
}    
?>
<!-- form begin -->
<form action="" method="post">    
    <?php
    for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {    
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='avar[$i]'/></td>";
    }
    ?>    
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
<!-- form end -->
```

Comment: @user2431351: try the full code. The form submits to itself. I've tested it here and it's working.

Comment: Worked thanks. Was doing one more silly mistake. anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your form, you don't need to assign index values to the array. You can just leave empty brackets for each field:

```
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {    
    echo "<td><input type='text' name='avar[]'/></td>";
}
```

To retrieve the values:

```
if (isset($_POST['avar'])){
    foreach ($_POST['avar'] as $key => $value){
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your dynamically created html, what you assigned as the name of your input tag is:
    `"avar[" . $i . "]"`
and when you want to retrive it you should use:

```
$_POST['avar[' . $i . ']']
```

but this a not a good idea to use array like name for haml tag names. cause you can't set tag names as arrays and retrive them like array when posting them.